# How to pass php variable to a new page for deleting a row from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

On the list.php page, I am passing a variable using hidden input method in form.

This form redirects to listd.php where the variable is used to run an SQL query to delete a particular row from the database where the variable==name.
If I print the variable on listd.php before processing SQL query then it is visible but during when query is processed it gives unidentified index error.

The code in listd.php works if I take input from the user on the same page.

list.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title> Sports </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Great+Vibes|Roboto|Barrio" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


<?php
require ("config.php");
?>




<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h3> List Events</h3>
<?php 
        session_start();



        if($_SESSION['username'])
            echo "<h2>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."!</h2>";
        else
                header('location:index.php');


      //session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        echo "<h3><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></h3>";
      ?>   


</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event </th>
        <th>Add</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     <!--
          <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      -->
     <?php



      {$result="SELECT name FROM events";
     $q = mysqli_query($conn,$result) or die(mysql_error());
         while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
     {  

         echo "<tr> <td>";
         echo $row['name'];
         echo "</td>";

         echo "<td>";
         echo '<a href="adde.php"><button> Add </button></a> <br><br>';
         echo "</td>";

         echo "<td>";
        echo '<form action="liste.php" method="post" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="';?>
    <?php echo $row['name']; 
    echo'"> <input type="submit" value="Edit">';
     echo "</form>";
        echo "</td>";


         echo "<td>";
         echo '<form action="listd.php" method="post" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="del2" value="';?>
    <?php echo $row['name']; 
    echo'"> <input type="submit" value="Delete">';
         echo "</td>";

         echo "</form>";


     }


}

    ?>  

      <!--  
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>

      -->


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

listd.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title> Sports </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Great+Vibes|Roboto|Barrio" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


<?php
require ("config.php");
?>




<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h3> Events </h3>


<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid text-primary text-center">


<br>
<a href="adde.php"><button class="btn"> Add </button></a> <br><br>
<a href="edite.php"><button class="btn"> Edit </button></a> <br><br>
<a href="deleteev.php"><button class="btn"> Delete </button></a> <br><br>
<a href="viewe.php"><button class="btn"> View </button> </a><br><br>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
        session_start();    
?>
<form action="listd.php" method="post" class="a">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td> Category Name </td>
    <td>
    <strong>
    <?php echo $_POST["del2"]; 
    $k=$_POST['del2'];
    ?>
    </strong>
    </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"> </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</form>




<?php

$event=$k;

if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'] )&& $event )
{   
    $sql="DELETE FROM events WHERE name='$event'";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
        echo "deleted  Succesfully";
        //header('location:listd.php'); 
        }
    else
            echo "error";

}   

 ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: why have you got two forms? You go from list.php (specifying a delete action), and then require the user to press delete _again_ to carry out the action. Does it really need double-confirming like this? Not very user-friendly, unless this is a very dangerous action or something. A Yes/No dialog box guarding the first form would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Anyway this is also the source of your problem. $k is not preserved on the second postback. Requests are _stateless_. When you submit the second form, the listd.php script runs again from the start, and the values assigned to variables the last time it ran. This is the normal behaviour of HTTP requests in general. You'd need to put the value into a hidden field on your second firm (in listd.php) in order for it to be sent to the server again (as a POST variable) in the second postback to listd.

Comment: I am learning the basics as of now but thanks for the information. I will try to learn about the security issues.

Comment: The second form is not necessary. How to do it just after clicking delete button? I attempted to send the value again in the second form but it didn't work.

Comment: No problem. It helps to do it correctly from the start, then you get into good habits. Any tutorial you may be following which doesn't show this is encouraging bad practice and is probably a load of junk

Comment: I will try to post an answer on how to do it with one form. Please wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not necessary to use two forms to do this, unless this is a very dangerous action. this is also the source of your problem. $k is not preserved on the second postback. Requests are stateless. When you submit the second form, the listd.php script runs again from the start, and the values assigned to variables the last time it ran. This is the normal behaviour of HTTP requests in general.

A single-form version might look like this:

**list.php**

```
<?php 
//this needs to be before anything else otherwise the redirect might fail due to headers already sent.
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //corrected to use isset(). Only one test for this is needed.
{
    echo "<h2>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."!</h2>";
    echo "<h3><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></h3>";
}
else
{
    header('location:index.php');
    die(); //script needs to die because webcrawlers/bots will ignore the redirect header, and view the rest of the page anyway, without permission. Using die() means the rest of the page never gets output.
}
?>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title> Sports </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Great+Vibes|Roboto|Barrio" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<?php
require ("config.php");
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h3> List Events</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
$message = null; //will hold any extra message to the user resulting from data processing actions (such as delete)

//only run the next section if del2 has been submitted from a postback.
if(isset($_POST['del2']))
{
  $event = $_POST['del2'];
  $sql= "DELETE FROM events WHERE name='$event'"; //here you should use parameterised queries, I will leave it to you to look this up online, using the link I gave in the comments.

  if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
    $message = "Deleted succesfully";
  }
  else
  {
    $message = "error";
    //here you should check mysqli_error() and log the output somewhere (not visible to the user)
  }
}  
?>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <!-- here is an example of how you can inject the confirmation message into somewhere suitable in the page. You can modify this to suit your needs. -->
  <?php if ($message != null) { echo "<p><b>".$message."</b></p>"; } ?>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event </th>
        <th>Add</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     <?php
     $result="SELECT name FROM events";
     $q = mysqli_query($conn,$result) or die(mysqli_error()); //corrected to use mysqli_error not mysql_error
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
     {  
        echo "<tr> <td>";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<a href="adde.php"><button> Add </button></a> <br><br>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<form action="liste.php" method="post" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="';
        echo $row['name']; 
        echo'"> <input type="submit" value="Edit">';
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<form action="list.php" method="post" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="del2" value="';
        echo $row['name']; 
        echo'"> <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?");>'; //adds a confirmation dialog box to the delete button
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</form>";
     }
?>  
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You do not need **listd.php** at all.

P.S. A separate hint: I see you are copying the same HTML `<head>` etc material into every page script. This is not necessary. You can create two files e.g. `header.php` and `footer.php`. In `header.php` you can put the opening `<html>` and `<head>` tags right down to `<body>` and any other enclosing tags necessary for the consistent layout of all your pages. Then in `footer.php` you can put the equivalent closing tags. And then in all the other pages of your site you can simply write `<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>` as the first line and `<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>` as the last line. Then any changes you need to make to the headers (e.g. new CSS files or something) are automatically applied to all the pages without tedious copy/paste actions. Although I suggested that you remove your second script here, you can do this for any other pages in your site. It's also a good general principle of code re-use which you can apply to all kinds of situations in your future code.

P.P.S. I'd also consider using an up-to-date doctype. The HTML5 doctype declaration is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This will likely result in more consistent behaviour of the HTML and CSS in your page, and future-proofs your application against deprecation of older doctypes which are no longer in current use.

Comment: I am not getting any errors but delete is not working.

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry. If you looked carefully at what happened in your browser's address bar when you submitted the form you might have seen it - the form should post back to list.php not listd.php. If you've removed listd.php as I suggested then you should have got a 404 error. I will amend the answer. Note that the "action" attribute of the delete form now points to "list.php".

Comment: Thank you very much.That works. I had tried to change the address to list.php but it didn't work that time. Did you change anything else and how to do the edit part since that would require a second form.

Comment: I didn't change anything else significant, no. For the editing you'd need to write the ID value passed from your first form into a hidden field on your second form (in liste.php) in order for it to be sent to the server again (as a POST variable) in the second postback to liste.php. That way the ID value is passed on from one postback to the next.